# How can I get the latest commit details from the GitHub Action?

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I've set up a GitHub Actions workflow to trigger on each push to the main branch, and I'm using a YAML script to extract commit details like the `commit message`, `file changes` (List of filename which got changed), and `code modifications` (Actually what code added in which line), `GitHub repoURL`. However, I've encountered an issue where the expect `commit name`,`GitHub repository URL` other are not being correctly extracted from the latest commit. The workflow successfully retrieves the commit message, but the other fields remain empty. I'm seeking assistance in debugging and refining my YAML script to ensure that all relevant commit details are properly extracted and send to my express backend.

My yml file :

```
name: Extrat details

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  publish-post:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set commit details
        id: commit-details
        run: |
          COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%s")
          CHANGES=$(git diff --name-status ${{ github.sha }}^@)
          CODE_CHANGES=$(git diff ${{ github.sha }}^@)

          # If the changes are empty, try using GITHUB_SHA directly
          if [ -z "$CHANGES" ]; then
            CHANGES=$(git diff --name-status ${{ github.sha }})
            CODE_CHANGES=$(git diff ${{ github.sha }})
          fi

          REPO_URL="https://github.com/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}"

          echo "::set-output name=commit_message::$COMMIT_MESSAGE"
          echo "::set-output name=changes::$CHANGES"
          echo "::set-output name=code_changes::$CODE_CHANGES"
          echo "::set-output name=github_repo_url::$REPO_URL"

      - name: Trigger extract
        run: |
          COMMIT_MESSAGE="${{ steps.commit-details.outputs.commit_message }}"
          CHANGES="${{ steps.commit-details.outputs.changes }}"
          CODE_CHANGES="${{ steps.commit-details.outputs.code_changes }}"
          REPO_URL="${{ steps.commit-details.outputs.github_repo_url }}"

          echo "Commit Message: $COMMIT_MESSAGE"
          echo "Changes: $CHANGES"
          echo "Code Changes: $CODE_CHANGES"
          echo "GitHub Repo URL: $REPO_URL"

          curl_data="{\"commitMessage\": \"$COMMIT_MESSAGE\", \"changes\": \"$CHANGES\", \"codeChanges\": \"$CODE_CHANGES\", \"githubRepoUrl\": \"$REPO_URL\"}"

          echo "Data to be sent: $curl_data"

          curl -X POST <my-express-server-url> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$curl_data"
```